# How do I dismiss the iOS keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have a UITextfield that i'd like to dismiss the keyboard for. I can't seem to make the keyboard go away no matter what code i use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift) (or the opposite, that post is a duplicate of this, with slightly more specific context)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
[myTextField resignFirstResponder]
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield), second paragraph in the Showing and Hiding the Keyboard section.

Answer (score 193):

If you have multiple text fields and don't know which one is first responder (or you simply don't have access to the text fields from wherever you are writing this code) you can call `endEditing:` on the parent view containing the text fields.

In a view controller's method, it would look like this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

The parameter forces the text field to resign first responder status. If you were using a delegate to perform validation and wanted to stop everything until the text field's contents were valid, you could also code it like this:

```
BOOL didEndEditing = [self.view endEditing:NO];
if (didEndEditing) {
    // on to the next thing...
} else {
    // text field must have said to first responder status: "never wanna give you up, never wanna let you down"
}
```

The `endEditing:` method is much better than telling individual text fields to `resignFirstResponder`, but for some reason I never even found out about it until recently.

Comment: Damnit! I can't believe I just got rickrolled in a code comment.

Comment: @Lytol the point of rickrolling (aka bait-and-switch) is to bait people with a lie, then redirecting them to someone singing "`Never gonna tell a lie`", so we're NOT rickrolled in the slightest (as the lie is missing, it's just an answer with nice joke).

Answer (score 11):

I've discovered a case where `endEditing` and `resignFirstResponder` fail. This has worked for me in those cases.

#### ObjC

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];    
[self setEditing:NO];
```

#### Swift

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

There are cases where **no text field is the first responder** but the keyboard is on screen.
In these cases, the above methods fail to dismiss the keyboard.

One example of how to get there:

1. push the ABPersonViewController on screen programmatically; open any contact;
2. touch the "note" field (which becomes first responder and fires up the keyboard);
3. swipe left on any other field to make the "delete" button appear;
4. by this point you have no first responder among the text fields (just check programmatically) but the keyboard is still there. Calling [view endEditing:YES] does nothing.

In this case you also need to ask the view controller to exit the editing mode:

```
[viewController setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you add and action on your header file:

```
-(IBAction)removeKeyboard;
```

And in the implementation, write something like this:

```
-(IBAction)removeKeyboard
{
[self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

In the NIB file, connect from the UITextFiled to the File's Owner on the option DidEndOnExit. That way, when you press return, the keyboard will disappear.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

In your view controller YourViewController.h file, make sure you implement UITextFieldDelegate protocol :

```
@interface YourViewController : <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

Then, in YourViewController.m file, implement the following instance method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.yourTextField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [self.yourTextField2 resignFirstResponder];
    ...
    [self.yourTextFieldn resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To resign any text field in the app

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
```

This approach is clean and guarantied to work because the keyWindow is, by definition, the root view of all possible views displaying a keyboard ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621612-iskeywindow)):

> The key window receives keyboard and other non-touch related events. Only one window at a time may be the key window.

Answer (score 3):

This will resign one particular text field

```
// Swift
TextField.resignFirstResponder()

// Objective C
[TextField resignFirstResponder];
```

To resign any text field use below code

```
// Swift
self.view!.endEditing(true)

// Objective C
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

as a last resort

```
let dummyTextView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
view.addSubview(dummyTextView)
dummyTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
dummyTextView.resignFirstResponder()
dummyTextView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: I had a UI where I had a `UITextField` that was first responder but a popover showing suggestions also active. Closing the keyboard with the hide button did not hide the keyboard somehow. This code helped me here, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know which textField is the first responder you can find it.  I use this function:

```
UIView *resignFirstResponder(UIView *theView)
{
    if([theView isFirstResponder])
    {
        [theView resignFirstResponder];
        return theView;
    }
    for(UIView *subview in theView.subviews)
    {
        UIView *result = resignFirstResponder(subview);
        if(result) return result;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then in your code call:

```
    UIView *resigned = resignFirstResponder([UIScreen mainScreen]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just replace `yourTextFieldName` with, you guessed it! your textfield. This will close the keyboard.

```
[yourTextFieldName resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)methodName
{
    [textFieldName resignFirstResponder];
}
```

call this method (methodName) with didEndOnExit

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 3**

You can hide the keyboard like this:

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

If you want to hide the keyboard when the user press the "intro" button, you have to implement the following `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // your code

    [textField reloadInputViews];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**3 Simple & Swift steps**

Add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your class as below:

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //class implementation 
}
```

in class implementation, add the delegate function `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`:

```
internal func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

and as a last step, set your `UITextField`(s) delegate(s) to self, in somewhere appropriate. For example, inside the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextField1.delegate = self
    myTextField2.delegate = self
    ..
    ..
}
```

Now, whenever user hits the return key, keyboard will dismiss.

I prepared an example snippet too, you can check it from [here](https://gist.github.com/MertCelik/a3fb63f2d660a1690369d6813ae4261f).

Answer (score -1):

1. Set up the "Did End On Exit" event in Xcode (right click on your text field).

   [image: Screenshot]
2. Realize this method:

   ```
   -(IBAction) closeKeyboard:(id) sender {
       [_txtField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   ```