# How to make a keyboard return on the done button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikeyboard, custom-cell

I have created a custom cell, containing a text field. I would like the keyboard to disappear when the user presses the done button (as seen in the screen shot below).

The custom cell is located in "AccountViewCell". In my code, I call and display this custom cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AccessCard";
        static NSString *Cellnib = @"AccountViewCell";

        AccountViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:Cellnib owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (AccountViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:3];
        }

        cell.data.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Password";
        static NSString *Cellnib = @"AccountViewCell";

        AccountViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:Cellnib owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (AccountViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:4];
        }

        cell.data.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The user is able to input text, however I cannot seem to make the keyboard disappear.

I have also created a method in AccountViewCell to hide the keyboard:

```
- (void)textfieldInput
{
    UIToolbar* padToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    padToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(doneWithPad)];
    [doneButton setWidth:65.0f];

    padToolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelPad)],
                        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                        doneButton,
                        nil];

    [padToolBar sizeToFit];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = padToolBar;

}
```

But when I call it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, it does not work.

```
AccountViewCell* keyboard = [[AccountViewCell alloc] init];
[keyboard textfieldInput];
```

I am wondering if there is a way to hide the keyboard when the done key is pressed. A screen shot of my application is below:

[image: keyboard does not disappear]

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906246/how-do-i-dismiss-the-ios-keyboard

Comment: I have tried that code as well, but it does not work. I am not quite sure as to where I should put it.

[myTextField resignFirstResponder]

Would I put it into the cellForRowAtIndexPath method or in the AccountViewCell class?

Comment: - (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [aTextBox resignFirstResponder];
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274319/how-do-you-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-editing-a-uitextfield

Comment: @SulaimanMajeed See the second link provided by akash. That other question has answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the Done button's action method use this one line code:

`[myTextField resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: What do you mean by "Make my control's delegate to my class"? How would I go about doing this? And then, would I put that one line of code into my CellForRowAtIndexPath method or in my AccountViewCell class?

Comment: On your done button's action method put this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Inlucde `UITextFeildDelegate` method in #.h file

Provide `[textfeild setDelegate:self];`

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

include

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: The `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method is called when the text field is no longer the first responder. So it makes no sense to call `resignFirstResponder` in this method. And none of this will be called when the "return" key is pressed.

Comment: check with my answer. Its unfortunately displayed that method.

Answer (score 0):

You must impliment the `UITextViewDelegate` in your header file, and then set the delegate of your text views to be your delegate. Often you'd do this all in the same class file so you could do

```
aTextField.delegate = self;
```

Once your delegate is set you can use the appropriate delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is not the proper delegate method for handling the "return" key being pressed in a text field.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting your UITextField in the .xib file, connect the destination to DidEndOnExit.