# Close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I have been looking all over for this but I can't seem to find it.  I know how to dismiss the keyboard using `Objective-C` but I have no idea how to do that using `Swift`? Does anyone know?

Comment: How are you doing it in Objective-C? It's normally a conversion from one syntax to the other, and rarely a matter of different methods/conventions.

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880482/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-away-across-the-entire-app/39880997#39880997).

Answer (score 1509, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
          
    //Looks for single or multiple taps. 
     let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false 

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Here is another way to do this task if you are going to use this functionality in multiple `UIViewControllers`:

```
// Put this piece of code anywhere you like
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false            
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Now in every `UIViewController`, all you have to do is call this function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() 
}
```

This function is included as a standard function in my repo which contains a lot of useful Swift Extensions like this one, check it out: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Comment: This approach adds flexibility and reusability. In case `tableView` isn't part of the app can be substituted by any other `view`.

Comment: @Esq Do I have to add this on each view or in ViewController only.

Comment: View controller only. But if you have multiple viewcontrollers and different screens, you need to do it in each screen. But the main view, should be containing all other views as subviews in that vc.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me but the UITextFieldDelegate answer by @King-Wizard did.

Comment: Since Swift 2 in the first answer, replace this line-> let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.dismissKeyboard))

Comment: it breaks tableviewcell's segue on a tableviewcontroller

Comment: This shouldn't break stuff. Maybe there is something else in your code?

Comment: This is one of the most helpful extensions I have ever come across! Thank you! The only caution I would extend is that this can interfere with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Thanks. What kind a precautions do you recommend for this? Please feel to send a pull request if you have some ideas

Comment: Messes with tableviews. The answer below by @King-Wizard is money.

Comment: This answer does not work for me. The UI becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I have my TextView in a static tableView which also contains a PickerView and Button, tapping either of the other controls does not trigger the tap gesture action to hide the keyboard. Any ideas?

Comment: This is messing my TableVew, didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method is nat called. Any ideas?

Comment: Just discovered this question and implemented that method. That thing with "didSelectRow" of tableView/UICollectionView not calling literally drove me crazy. The solution is: Simply add this to your extension: `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`. That solved it for me at least. Hope this helps somebody

Comment: don't forget to set UITapGestureRecognizer **cancelTouches** to false if your view controller has a **tableView** this will intercept tap and prevent _didSelectRowAtIndexPath_ to be called
`tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Comment: @Esqarrouth, Can you please edit your answer to include "tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false". Without that, it cancels touches and disables interactions in subviews.

Comment: Works nice except on a table view that has a selectable cell that segues into another view. The tap gets in the way and prevents the segue/cell touch.

Comment: I implement this method, but if I have tableview that inside the cell I have button, when I tap the button, It hide the keyboard first, and then the button got tapped after tap again. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Best solution! 
For Swift 4, don't forget to add @objc before func dismissKeyboard()

Comment: I had problem with this extension, for instance i have button on the view and i click on the button, the keyboard will close but the button action will not work properly

Comment: All I needed was the `view.endEditing(true)` part for Did End Editing. 

Comment: there's a problem with this answer, I have a button in the view I wanna perform this action in, when the keyboard is up and I click on the button, the keyboard will disappear but I won't get the complete button action, some weird behavior

Comment: Genius piece of code which I am now adding to my AppDelegate before the class definition or a globals file which can be referenced anywhere.  I made 1 change in that I extended UITableViewController.  Remember you must also change it in the .dismiss keyboard section also.  GREAT!!  Thank you!

Comment: @ArashAfsharpour I have the same problem. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This will fail if user performs swipe (for example trying to scroll tableview or interactive modal). See my answer for solution that fixes that.

Answer (score 137):

An answer to your question on how to dismiss the keyboard in Xcode 6.1 using Swift below:

```
import UIKit

class ItemViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textFieldItemName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var textFieldQt: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var textFieldMoreInfo: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textFieldItemName.delegate = self
        textFieldQt.delegate = self
        textFieldMoreInfo.delegate = self
    }

                       ...

    /**
     * Called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
     */
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


   /**
    * Called when the user click on the view (outside the UITextField).
    */
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

([Source of this information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YMNmLK0694)).

Comment: Great piece of code, thanks!  
touchesBegan was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This didn't quite work for me.  If I tap on the view controller's view it works.  If I tap on a control item in the view, the keyboard doesn't dismiss.

Comment: This is the best solution I have seen so far. Small note: in newer Swift the override signature changed a bit. You need to add _ before touches: 
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)

Comment: This one should probably be marked as correct one. The current accepted answer makes every button in the view not responsive when keyboard is showing.

Comment: This doesn't work when tapping inside a tableview or any scrollable.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it doesn't interfere with other tap events.

Answer (score 63):

### Swift 4 working

Create extension as below & call `hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()` in your Base view controller.

```
//
//  UIViewController+Extension.swift
//  Project Name
//
//  Created by ABC on 2/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 ABC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                         action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func hideKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Most important thing to call in your Base View Controller so that no need to call all time in all view controllers.

Answer (score 39):

You can call

```
resignFirstResponder()
```

on any instance of a UIResponder, such as a UITextField. If you call it on the view that is currently causing the keyboard to be displayed then the keyboard will dismiss.

Comment: In a situation where you don't exactly know the first responder, resignFirstResponder() can lead to a heap of trouble. Esq's answer below (using view.doneEditing()) is a lot more appropriate

Comment: Whenever I use resignFirstResponder on my textField the app crashes. I tried everything I could think of, and looked around the web for a fix. Nothing helps me. Would you happen to know why that happens?

Comment: As shiser said this is not the best solution. plus it doesn't work in all situations.

Answer (score 32):

**swift 5** just two lines is enough. Add into your `viewDidLoad` should work.

```
 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
 view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

If your tap gesture blocked some other touches, then add this line:

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Answer (score 24):

for Swift 3 it is very simple

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

if you want to hide keyboard on pressing RETURN key

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

but in second case you will also need to pass delegate from all textFields to the ViewController in the Main.Storyboard

Comment: I get `unrecognized selector sent to instance` with this code.

Answer (score 21):

```
//Simple exercise to demonstrate, assuming the view controller has a //Textfield, Button and a Label. And that the label should display the //userinputs when button clicked. And if you want the keyboard to disappear //when clicken anywhere on the screen + upon clicking Return key in the //keyboard. Dont forget to add "UITextFieldDelegate" and 
//"self.userInput.delegate = self" as below

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var userInput: UITextField!
    @IBAction func transferBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
                display.text = userInput.text

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//This is important for the textFieldShouldReturn function, conforming to textfieldDelegate and setting it to self
        self.userInput.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

//This is for the keyboard to GO AWAYY !! when user clicks anywhere on the view
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


//This is for the keyboard to GO AWAYY !! when user clicks "Return" key  on the keyboard

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Swift 3:
Easiest way to dismiss keyboard:

```
  //Dismiss keyboard method
    func keyboardDismiss() {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    //ADD Gesture Recignizer to Dismiss keyboard then view tapped
    @IBAction func viewTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        keyboardDismiss()
    }

    //Dismiss keyboard using Return Key (Done) Button
    //Do not forgot to add protocol UITextFieldDelegate 
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        keyboardDismiss()

        return true
    }
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the view.endEditing(true) call  is simpler in that it doesn't require you to store a variable or assume you only have one text field.

Answer (score 13):

In swift you can use

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Just one line of code in `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. But as someone who started app development on Android and then also started developing apps for iOS I'm always astounded that this is not the default behaviour, because unlike on Android, there is no way for the user to dismiss the keyboard otherwise and app is effectively locked up!

Answer (score 12):

To expand on [Esqarrouth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27079103/409958), I always use the following to dismiss the keyboard, especially if the class from which I am dismissing the keyboard **does not have a `view` property and/or is not a subclass of `UIView`**.

```swift
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
```

Or, for convenience,

```swift
UIApplication.endEditing(true)
```

with the following extension to the `UIApplication` class:

```
extension UIApplication {

    /// Dismisses the keyboard from the key window of the
    /// shared application instance.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - force: specify `true` to force first responder to resign.
    open class func endEditing(_ force: Bool = false) {
        shared.endEditing(force)
    }

    /// Dismisses the keyboard from the key window of this 
    /// application instance.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - force: specify `true` to force first responder to resign.
    open func endEditing(_ force: Bool = false) {
        keyWindow?.endEditing(force)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Dash's answer is correct and preferred. A more "scorched earth" approach is to call `view.endEditing(true)`. This causes `view` and all its subviews to `resignFirstResponder`. If you don't have a reference to the view you'd like to dismiss, this is a hacky but effective solution.

> Note that personally I think you should have a reference to the view you'd like to have resign first responder. `.endEditing(force: Bool)` is a barbaric approach; please don't use it.

Answer (score 11):

I found the best solution included the accepted answer from @Esqarrouth, with some adjustments:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboardView")
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboardView() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

The line `tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false` was critical: it ensures that the `UITapGestureRecognizer` does not prevent other elements on the view from receiving user interaction.

The method `dismissKeyboard()` was changed to the slightly less elegant `dismissKeyboardView()`. This is because in my project's fairly old codebase, there were numerous times where `dismissKeyboard()` was already used (I imagine this is not uncommon), causing compiler issues.

Then, as above, this behaviour can be enabled in individual View Controllers:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I have use IQKeyBoardManagerSwift for keyboard. it is easy to use.
just Add pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

Import IQKeyboardManagerSwift and write code on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`.

```
///add this line 
IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
```

Answer (score 10):

In storyboard:

1. select the TableView
2. from the the right-hand-side, select the attribute inspector
3. in the keyboard section - select the dismiss mode you want

Comment: can't find that item, where is it and what does it look like? I'm in the attribute inspector of a textField

Comment: You need to look at the TableView not TextField

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3:**

Extension with `Selector` as parameter to be able to do additional stuff in the dismiss function and `cancelsTouchesInView` to prevent distortion with touches on other elements of the view.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardOnTap(_ selector: Selector) {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector)
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardOnTap(#selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    // do aditional stuff
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use **IQKeyboardmanager** that will help you solve easy.....

/////////////////////////////////////////

![ how to disable the keyboard..][1]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad() 
      username.delegate = self
      password.delegate = self
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool // called when   'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
   {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true;
   }

   override func touchesBegan(_: Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) {
     username.resignFirstResponder()
     password.resignFirstResponder()
     self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use a scroll view, It could be much simpler.

[image]

Just select `Dismiss interactively` in storyboard.

Answer (score 8):

Add this extension to your ViewController :

```
  extension UIViewController {
// Ends editing view when touches to view 
  open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4, add @objc:

In the viewDidLoad:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Function:

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
  view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  import UIKit

  class ItemViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           self.nameTextField.delegate = self
     }

    // Called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            textField.resignFirstResponder()
             return true
     }

 // Called when the user click on the view (outside the UITextField).

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)    {
      self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As a novice programmer it can be confusing when people produce more skilled and unnecessary responses...You do not have to do any of the complicated stuff shown above!...

Here is the simplest option...In the case your keyboard appears in response to the textfield - Inside your touch screen function just add the **resignFirstResponder** function. As shown below - the keyboard will close because the First Responder is released (exiting the Responder chain)...

```
override func touchesBegan(_: Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?){
    MyTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This one liner resigns Keyboard from all(any) the UITextField in a UIView

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 4):

Posting as a new answer since my edit of @King-Wizard's answer was rejected.

Make your class a delegate of the UITextField and override touchesBegan.

**Swift 4**

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    //Called when 'return' key is pressed. Return false to keep the keyboard visible.
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Called when the user clicks on the view (outside of UITextField).
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift3**

Register an event recogniser in viewDidLoad

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyBoard))
```

then we need to add the gesture into the view in same viewDidLoad.

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then we need to initialise the registered  method

```
func hideKeyBoard(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil){
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to dismiss the keyboard by tapping anywhere else, in 2 lines using **Swift 5**.

(I hate to add another answer, but since this is the top result on Google I will to help rookies like me.)

In your ViewController.swift, find the `viewDidLoad()` function.

Add these 2 lines:

```
let tap: UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a tap gesture recognizer to resign the keyboard. :D

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
    backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
    func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    textFieldtwo.resignFirstResponder()
    textFieldthree.resignFirstResponder()

    println("tappped")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to simply add a big button with no content that lies underneath all views you might need to touch.
Give it an action named:

```
@IBAction func dismissKeyboardButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

The problem with a gesture recognizer was for me, that it also caught all touches I wanted to receive by the tableViewCells.

Answer (score 2):

If you have other views that should receive the touch as well you have to set 
`cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Like this:

```
let elsewhereTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    elsewhereTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(elsewhereTap)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a succinct way of doing it:

```
let endEditingTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
endEditingTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(endEditingTapGesture)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap)))

}

func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("tapped")
        view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Try this,It's Working

Answer (score 2):

how to dismiss keyboard when you click anywhere to close it

```
 //Setup dismiss keyboard gesture
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))

     view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
 }
 //Calling this function when the tapped
 @objc func dismissKeyboard() {

    view.endEditing(true)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## When there is more than one text field in the view

To follow [@modocache's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24126929/37168) to avoid calling `view.endEditing()`, you could keep track of the text field that became first responder, but that is messy and error-prone.

An alternative is to call `resignFirstResponder()` **on all text fields in the viewcontroller**. Here's an example of creating a collection of all text fields (which in my case was needed for validation code anyway):

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

var allTextFields: Array<UITextField>!  // Forced unwrapping so it must be initialized in viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.allTextFields = [self.firstName, self.lastName, self.email]
}
```

With the collection available, it's a simple matter to iterate through all of them:

```
private func dismissKeyboard()
{
    for textField in allTextFields
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

So now you can call `dismissKeyboard()` in your gesture recognizer (or wherever is appropriate for you). Drawback is that you must maintain the list of `UITextField`s when you add or remove fields.

Comments welcome. If there is a problem with calling `resignFirstResponder()` on controls that aren't first responder, or if there's an easy and guaranteed non-buggy way to track the current first responder, I'd love to hear about it!

Answer (score 1):

I worked out on uisearchbar . See mine.

```
import UIKit

class BidderPage: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

     let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

// Set recogniser as public in case of tableview and didselectindexpath.


    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)

    {

        recognizer.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap:")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    }

    func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        biddersearchbar .resignFirstResponder()
    }
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        view .removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this **one-liner**:

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboardFromView:"))
```

Just put that in the override viewDidLoad function in whichever subclassed UIViewController you want it to occur, and then put the following code in a new empty file in your project called "UIViewController+dismissKeyboard.swift":

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    // This function is called when the tap is recognized
    func dismissKeyboardFromView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
        let view = sender?.view
        view?.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got you fam

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() /*This ensures that our view loaded*/
    self.textField.delegate = self /*we select our text field that we want*/   
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismissKeyboard")))
}

func dismissKeyboard(){ /*this is a void function*/
    textField.resignFirstResponder() /*This will dismiss our keyboard on tap*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this simple solution:
1. Add UITapGestureRecognizer to your view Controller
2. Add IBAction to your UITapGestureRecognizer
3. Finally you can resign the first responder

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

@IBOutlet var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBAction func dismissUsingGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
   self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    label.text = textField.text!
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: you are not calling super

Answer (score 1):

Able to achieve this by adding a global tap gesture recognizer to the `window` property in the `AppDelegate`.

This was a very catch all approach and might not be the desired solution for some but it worked for me. Please let me know if there any pitfalls to this solution.

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Globally dismiss the keyboard when the "background" is tapped.
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(
            UITapGestureRecognizer(
              target: window, 
              action: #selector(UIWindow.endEditing(_:))
            )
        )

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: The tap gesture steals touch events from a UITabBar / UITabViewController unless you call `tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen it mentioned, but NotificationCenter can tell you when the keyboard opens and closes. For example, this can be used if you want to change cancelsTouchesInView or remove the gesture recognizer all together.

Example:

```
var dismissKeyboardGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Setup dismiss keyboard gesture
    self.dismissKeyboardGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))

    //Add Notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name:UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidHide), name:UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardDidShow() {
    dismissKeyboardGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(dismissKeyboardGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func keyboardDidHide() {
    dismissKeyboardGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(dismissKeyboardGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is by selecting the text field and using the method endEditing(true)

e.g

```
exampleTextField.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dissmiss the keyboard, when you want go to the next button action or anyplace.

you can simply add the below line, Replace the textfield name of yours.

billTextField.endEditing(true)
or
billTextField.resignFirstResponder()

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Below function hides the keyboard when we click outside the textBox
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
```

You can put this code in your ViewController and it will let you dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised, that none of the answers cover **all edge cases**. Possible edge cases in 2023:

1. User tries to swipe scrollview, tableview or modal view
2. User wants to exclude certain views from dismissing the keyboard
3. User taps on navigation bar (it's outside of view bounds so tap gesture wouldn't trigger there)

Why `UITapGesture`'s action is bad for this? UITapGestureRecognizer only calls its `action` if it triggers and it doesn't trigger if **touch moves**. So if you have a scrollview, or tableview, or interactive modal view and user tries to scroll/interact with them, the keyboard will fail to be dismissed. Furthermore, if you add gesture recognizer to your view controller, tapping navbar will fail to trigger the action as its outside of view's bounds. Lastly, there edge case where tap gesture doesn't work at all - swipe initiated from the cell that should not dismiss the keyboard (but the scroll should do it).

So we have established that we can't rely on `UITapGestureRecognizer` action, but what can we use instead? The `UIPanGesture` and its delegate.

To make the gesture recognizer transparent it needs to be defined with the following properties. This way it won't interfere with any other interactions. Put this code in your ViewController:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var tapOutsideGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let control = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectSwipe))
        control.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        control.delaysTouchesBegan = false
        control.delaysTouchesEnded = false

        control.delegate = self

        return control
    }()

    // This will be used to handle one edge case
    var viewOrigin: CGPoint?

    ...
}
```

Then we use the delegate to cancel any touches that begin outside the list of excluded view, but trigger our code instead. Put this anywhere, but its best to keep in your ViewController.swift file.

```
extension MyViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        // We capture origin of the view, to detect swipe/scroll anywhere in the display tree
        viewOrigin = view.convert(view.bounds.origin, to: nil)
        return endEditingIfNeeded(touch: touch)
    }

    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

In the code that triggers when user taps anywhere, we want to exclude some views from dismissing the keyboard. Put this code in your ViewController:

```
extension MyViewController {
    @objc func detectSwipe(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.state == .changed, let viewOrigin else { return }
        let newOrigin = view.convert(view.bounds.origin, to: nil)

        if abs(newOrigin.y - viewOrigin.y) > 1 || abs(newOrigin.x - viewOrigin.x) > 1 {
            tappedOutside()
        }
    }

    @objc func endEditingIfNeeded(touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        // Array of views that shouldn't dismiss the keyboard
        let exclude = [view.pickerContainerView, view.inputTextField]
        for target in exclude {
            // If tap origin is within excluded view, don't dismiss the keyboard
            if target.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: target)) {
                return true
            }
        }

        // If tap originates in a view different than exclusion list, dismiss the keyboard or perform some other action
        tappedOutside()
        return false
    }

    func tappedOutside() {
        // This line is optional and only should be used if you decide to add gesture recognizer to navigation controller (see explanation at the bottom of this answer)
        // navigationController?.view.removeGestureRecognizer(tapOutsideGestureRecognizer)
   }
```

There are two options to add this gesture recognizer:

1. Add to your view by calling `view.addGestureRecognizer(tapOutsideGestureRecognizer)`. It will work anywhere in the view, but if the view is presented in navigation controller, tapping navbar wouldn't trigger the code.
2. Add it to navigation view controller (or it could for example be tabbar controller), by calling `navigationController?.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapOutsideGestureRecognizer)`. If you go this route, **you must remove** gesture recognizer `endEditingIfNeeded` to prevent it from outliving the view.
   Last but not least. If you want to cover **whole** screen, not just the view area,

Answer (score -1):

try using this:

[self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: This is an Objective-C solution, but the OP asked for a Swift solution. Swift solutions are already posted.