# Close Keyboard in iOS on touch anywhere in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I know that to close the keyboard by touching anywhere else in Obj-C you would have to write

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_answerField isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != _answerField) {
    [_answerField resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

But how would you do that with Swift?

Thanks

Comment: There was this thread literally in the right hand side's "Related" column and apparently it's yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift?rq=1

Comment: you want us to translate the code for you?

Comment: This will only close the keyboard if `_answerField`, whatever that is, is the first responder.  What you really want is to call `endEditing:YES` on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the translation:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let touch = event.allTouches().anyObject() as UITouch
    if _answerField.isFirstResponder() && touch.view != _answerField {
        _answerField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

I recommend reading Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" book and looking over Apple's [beta documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0) involving their existing API's and how to interact with them.

Comment: Thanks.  XCode gives me a suggestion to change let touch = event.allTouches().anyObject() to let touch : AnyObject! = event.allTouches().anyObject()

Comment: This will only close the keyboard if `_answerField`, whatever that is, is the first responder.  What you really want is to call `endEditing:YES` on the view.  Otherwise, if you have multiple text fields, this code quickly become really silly.

Comment: Thanks for that nhgrif.  I only have one text field for this one but when I run this code, it gives me an error on ** and says use of unresolved identifier '**' and operator is an unknown binary operator

Comment: Sorry about that. Those should be `&&` instead. I also added the cast to UITouch that was causing the other warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as alternative assign UITapGestureRecognizer (with self.view.endEditing(true) ) to parent view