# how to make decimal keyboard go away in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am trying to make the decimal keyboard on iOS go away but I have not been successful because there is no return key.

Comment: Try this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift

Comment: usually `resignFirstResponder` or something

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

When the user touches somewhere other than the keyboard/textfield, it will dismiss.