# How to Dismiss keyboard when touching away across the entire app

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I have multiple textFields in different viewControllers where keyboard is popped up.

I know how to dismiss keyboard when user clicks on a different part of the screen but I don't want to go and hard code it into every corner of my app.

So is there anyway to enforce keyboard getting keyboard dismissed **everywhere on the app** when the user clicks *anywhere on the screen other than keyboard*?

I was thinking of extending the UIViewController, but I also have some textFields inside a view that I add as a subview. Perhaps there could be someway that I extend TextField class itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to create a **base** `UIViewController` and let each of your ViewControllers inherit it; override *touchesBegan* method in it:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

OR you can override *viewDidLoad* -in the base ViewController- and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view, as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Base.endEditing))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func endEditing() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: This can also be done via Swift Extensions with zero costs. You don't have to refactor all of your `UIViewController`

Comment: Imagine I have a viewController that has a button. And I tap on that button which is obviously a subview of the viewController. Then viewController won't get messaged anymore so the keyboard is still there. Am I right?

Comment: tapping on a button does NOT calls touchesBegan, you can solve this by adding "view.endEditing(true)" in the button's action... @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an extension of a view controller, if you want the keyboard dismissal to apply to all of them:

```
extension UIViewController {
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```