# Dismissing Keyboard for UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm new to Swift, and I was recently learning about `UITextField` and how it delegates. I was wondering if there was a simple way to dismiss the keyboard when taping outside of it (somewhere else in the view). Currently, I am using `UITapGestureRecognizer` to do this. It works, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Which delegate methods have you used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift)

Comment: [Solution is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift?rq=1) For Swift and objective

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to dismiss the keyboard by tapping anywhere on the screen

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

But be sure to set the delegates beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the delegate of `UITextField`, Like as `UITableviewDataSource,Delegate`. Write `yourTextFieldDelegate.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()`
2. Then, write this function:

   ```
   func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       titleTextField.resignFirstResponder()
       return true
   }
   ```