# TouchBegan method not working in swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, keyboard-events

I want to dismiss keypad when tap on anywhere on screen. For that I used `touchbegan` method but this method was not called.

Comment: show what you are trying..?

Comment: `touchBegan` on what? What view?

Comment: Educated guess , since i have no information on your code or views hirerchy . some other view prorbaly "steal" your touches .

Comment: show your code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift)

Comment: If my answer helped, accept it pls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `UITapGestureRecogniser` to view and dismiss keyboard.

**In viewdidLoad()**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeybord(_:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**In dismissKeybord**

```
func dismissKeybord(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me. Showing keyboard on touch to `textfields`. Hide on every other touches.

```
class LoginController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var userLogin: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPassword: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

      userLogin.delegate = self
      userPassword.delegate = self

      //For scrolling the view if keyboard on
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginController.keyboardWillShow),
                                             name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginController.keyboardWillHide),
                                             name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

      super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // OTHER METHODS

    var keyBoardAlreadyShowed = false //using this to not let app to scroll view
    //if we tapped UITextField and then another UITextField

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      if !keyBoardAlreadyShowed {
         view.frame.origin.y -= 50
         keyBoardAlreadyShowed = true
      }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
      view.frame.origin.y += 50
      keyBoardAlreadyShowed = false
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

You need to set `delegates` and `observers`

Answer (score 0):

If your touches are not eaten by other view, then i guess this will work

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            if touches.first != nil {
                view.endEditing(true)
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 :-

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case recently. Should work for you too.

1. Create a **UITapGestureRecognizer**.
2. In the **selector method** that is **endEditing** in the below code, simply call **self.view.endEditing(true)**.

(Please note, the parameter true is a value for animated)

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(endEditing))
        tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func endEditing() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```