# Hiding keyboard when pressing enter or clicking away on tableView with custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am new to Swift and have been struggling with hiding the keyboard when the textField is on a custom tableview cell. I think the problem stems from the textField Reference being in the TableViewCell class, but i can't be sure. I have tried everything and am a little lost.

My code consists of:

TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var userText: UITextField!
    @IBAction func answers(_ sender: UITextField)
    {
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

and TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    var textfield = TableViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myText = textfield.userText
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        myText?.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

I tried running the `textFieldShouldReturn` function from both classes but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift)

Comment: Have you tried the textField.resignFirstResponder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `UITextFieldDelegate` and delegate func from `UITableViewCell` 
then set delegate in `UITableViewController`->inside

```
`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)as! TableViewCell

    cell.userText.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

then you want to  add `textFieldShouldReturn` in `UITableViewController` and return true  try this

Answer (score 0):

Inside your  `textFieldShouldReturn` function insert `textField.resignFirstResponder`

Or in your `viewDidLoad`  insert `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag` or `.interactive` so it dismisses when you scroll if you want

Comment: func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            return true
        } still did not fix it for me

Comment: I think it has something to do with the reference for for textField being in the separate TableViewCell class but i cant be sure or how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried the dismiss on drag option? That's the most commonly used nowadays just swipe down and it closes the keyboard

Comment: I thought the dismiss on drag was for scrollView I'm not sure how to implement it for a tableView I would still need the keyboard to dismiss on return though.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function in your tableView cell class because you have declared delegate in tableviewCell's class.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      textField. resignFirstResponder() 
        return false
    }
```