# How to dismiss keyboard from textField

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard, textfield

I currently am trying to dismiss the keyboard from the previous text field when clicking a button. I currently have one method working to dismiss the keyboard, although it only dismisses it when the user taps away.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift). You might also consider doing some research into "resginFirstResponder"

Comment: And may be also [Best way to dismiss Keyboard in a View Controller iOS (Swift)](https://medium.com/@KaushElsewhere/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-a-view-controller-of-ios-3b1bfe973ad1)

Comment: self.view .endEditing(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call this method every time you wanted to resign the

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

and you can dismiss keyboard from every textfield you wanted , you can call this method :

```
myTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```