# Close iOS Keyboard by touching outside ( a smarter way)

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I have `UIViewController` with `UITextfield` and several other elements (several subviews and buttons). I want to close the keyboard when tapped somewhere outside of the `UITextfield`.

I know there is an answer [Close iOS Keyboard by touching anywhere using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top), but this way doesn't work if user taps on viewController's subviews or buttons.
I can add the similar `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each subViews and buttons, but is there a smarter way to resolve this?

Comment: Try this : **https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager** and put this line `IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` so when you touch outside it will dismiss keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIViewController{
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Also if you have elements in a UIScrollView, add this method too:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```