# Hide keyboard in view after inputting values?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a small calculator built into 3 different views. On all the calcuulators, I would like to have the keyboard disappear upon either tapping anywhere on the screen or upon pressing the button to calucate a value. Ive researched several sources and have become confused on how to implement any code for this. My calculator code is below. Thanks in advance!

```
class Calculators: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var fluidIn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var timeIn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dripIn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dripResult: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var weight: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var etomidate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var succ: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var roc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ketamine: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var lbsIn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var KgIn: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var KgOut: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var LbsOut: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {

        let Number2 = Double(weight.text!)
        let etommult = (0.3)
        let etomresult = Number2! * etommult
        etomidate.text = "\(etomresult)"

        etomidate.text = NSString(format:"%2.1f mg",etomresult)as String;

        let Number3 = Double(weight.text!)
        let succmult = (2.0)
        let succresult = Number3! * succmult
        succ.text = "\(succresult)"

        succ.text = NSString(format: "%2.1f mg",succresult)as String;

        let Number4 = Double(weight.text!)
        let rocmult = (1.0)
        let rocresult = Number4! * rocmult
        roc.text = "\(rocresult)"

        roc.text = NSString(format: "%2.1f mg",rocresult)as String;

        let Number5 = Double(weight.text!)
        let fentmult = (2.0)
        let fentresult = Number5! * fentmult
        ketamine.text = "\(fentresult)"

        ketamine.text = NSString(format: "%2.1f mg",fentresult)as String;

    }

    @IBAction func KgConv(_ sender: Any) {

       let kg = Double(lbsIn.text!)
       let kgmult = (2.2)
       let kgresult = kg! / kgmult
       KgOut.text = "\(kgresult)"

       KgOut.text = NSString(format: "%2.1f kg",kgresult)as String;

    }

    @IBAction func LbsConv(_ sender: Any) {

        let lbs = Double(KgIn.text!)
        let lbsmult = (2.2)
       let lbsresult = lbs! * lbsmult
    LbsOut.text = "\(lbsresult)"

    LbsOut.text = NSString(format: "%2.1f kg",lbsresult)as String;
    }

    @IBAction func dripCalc(_ sender: Any) {

        let cc = Double(fluidIn.text!)
        let min = Double(timeIn.text!)
        let fct = Double(dripIn.text!)
        let dripRes = (cc! * fct!) / min!

        dripResult.text = "\(dripRes)"
        dripResult.text = NSString(format: "%2.1f gtts/min",dripRes)as String;

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126678/close-ios-keyboard-by-touching-anywhere-using-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the below code whenever and wherever you want to hide the keyboard in viewController.

```
view.endEditing(true)
```