# Keyboard is not dismissing when navigating from another view ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, resignfirstresponder

I have two view controller. suppose, `viewcontroller1` and `viewcontroller2`.

In `viewcontroller1` I have a textview and a button. When I click textview keyboard open, and if press button keyboard dismiss nicely. I am using this code for dismiss keyboard.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
                                               to:nil
                                             from:nil
                                         forEvent:nil];
```

but, when keyboard open, and I go to `viewcontroller2` and then return to `viewcontroller1`, in viewWillAppear method I use same code for dismissing keyboard, but keyboard not dismiss. I am so much astonished to see this. please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dismiss the iOS keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906246/how-do-i-dismiss-the-ios-keyboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Get rid of that sending Action routine

First, remove this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
                                               to:nil
                                             from:nil
                                         forEvent:nil];
```

#### Option no.1

Now In your other ViewController's viewDidLoad, write this line:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

#### Option no.2

You can also resign the textField and textViews before navigating to second VC. E.g. Do it like this in your first VC's navigation code:

```
//Method moveToSecondVC()
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

#### Option no.3

If you are using segues, you can do it in prepareForSegue method like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

#### Option no.4

Alternatively, you can just write this line in `viewWillDisappear` method of your ViewControllers like:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```